# How to use svg tag in Lightning

Tags: lightning

Can anyone tell me how can i use `<svg> and <use>` tag in Lightning.I tried by creating [Lightning SVG](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/) as mentioned in this link,but still not getting it.

Comment: Did you try using a lightning:icon tag it can show images for you instead of you trying to use svg. If you want to use the Lightning svg please post the code where you are running into issues. For the link you gave all you need to do is to create a component using that code and call the SVG component whereever you want to display images something like below

Comment: @Mohith No i didnt tried using Lightning:icon,but i need to get panels and other grids in my lighting code. For example i am using this line: `<svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
              </svg>`   And i tried using SVGiocn component,but i am not getting again to use `<svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">`. I tried something like this: `<c:svgicon class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">`. It says unknown attribute aria-hidden.

Comment: <lightning-icon></lightning-icon>

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using a lightning:icon tag it can show images for you instead of you trying to use svg. If you want to use the Lightning svg please post the code where you are running into issues. For the link you gave all you need to do is to create a component using that code and call the SVG component whereever you want to display images something like below

```
<c:svgcomp svgPath='' name = '' class = '' assistiveText = ''/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Save yourself some trouble and use

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:close"/>
```

To display the Utility - Close icons for example

If you must use the `<svg>` tag you need to include the namespace in the enclosing element

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon icon-text-email slds-icon--small slds-m-right--x-small">
           <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.ResourceName, '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#ban)}"></use>
      </svg>
      <span id="err_text"></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use panels from SLDS which contains `<svg>` tags. Then i cannot use `<lightning:panels> `right?? Example consider this line `<svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">`. Can you suggest me any something for this.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal I already did.

Comment: `<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<div class="slds-grid">
  <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled slds-path__trigger slds-no-flex slds-m-horizontal--small" title="Open">
    <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
      <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#chevrondown"></use>
    </svg>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Open</span>
  </button>`

Comment: I have kept my code under `<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> </div>` still i am getting error saying **No component named `<svg>` found**